# Sumar subtotales en sub consulta mysql PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo 2 tablas: PEDIDOS (izquierda) Y PEDIDOS_DETALLE (derecha)

[image: PEDIDOS]
[image: PEDIDOS DETALLE]

mis pedidos los guardo asi:
en pedidos_detalle van todos los platos,precio,cantidad,y si es para llevar; y en pedidos va la informacion general del pedido: mesa,modalidad,etc:
ahora bien, al momento de hacer mi consulta para listar los pedidos yo la hago a la tabla pedidos, porque solo quiero mostrar la vista general del pedido (total, modalidad, mesa,mecero), no la descripcion del pedido.
quiero con un `left join` a `pedidos_detalle` extraer la suma de ( `precio` x `cantidad`) y generar un total de cada detalle de pedido de la tabla `pedidos_detalle`.
ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si se dan cuenta en pedidos_detalle aparece el precio y la cantidad por lo tanto el sub_total seria precio * cantidad.

entonces mi consulta mysql debe primero multiplicar el precio por la cantidad y luego sumar los subtotales de cada registro y generar un total.

**mi actual consulta y lo que yo intente:**

```
$query_pedidos = "
SELECT PE.id_reg,PE.id_pedido,PE.fecha_reg,PE.id_mesa,PE.modalidad,PE.costo_delivery,PE.medio_pago
FROM pedidos PE
LEFT JOIN pedidos_detalle PED ON PED.id_pedido = PE.id_pedido
WHERE PE.delet = '0'
";



$bd_pedidos = $bd->query($query_pedidos);





<table class="tbl-e1">
    <thead>
    <th>Pedido</th>
    <th data-tsort="disabled" data-tfilter="disabled" class="disabled-sort"></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php 
    while ($pedido = $bd_pedidos->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
    <tr pedido-estado="estado-1">
    <td>
    <div>Pedido pendiente</div>
    <div class="flex-ali-cen label-5">
    <div class="text_estado">PENDIENTE</div>
    <div><b>Mesa:</b> 35</div>
    </div>
    </td>
        <td width="20" class="td-opc" style="vertical-align:middle">
        <div class="td-grid-opc">
            <button class="btn-ico min"><img src="images/iconos/ver.svg"></button>  
            <button class="btn-ico min"><img src="images/iconos/plus.svg"></button>  
        <button class="btn-ico min"><img src="images/iconos/editar-pedido.svg"></button>  
        <button class="btn-ico min"><img src="images/iconos/anular.svg"></button>  
        </div>
  </td>
    </tr>



    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: disculpa amigo, cual es tu consulta acá, no sabes como realizar la operacion matematica mediante SQL ?

Comment: ya encontre la respuesta es: sum(subtotales * cantidad)
gracias por el interes amigo